# Complete Field Using Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

What I'm looking to do is when selecting a foreign key (in phpMyAdmin), a relating field to auto populate. For example:

Table 1 {
trackID: 1,
artist:,
artistID: 1
}

Table 2 {
artistID: 1,
artist: X
}

So when the foreign key artistID is selected then artist in table 1 to be automatically completed to X. Sorry if my explanation isn't good, I'll try my best to answer any questions..

Thank you.

Comment: what actually meant by > _automatically completed to X._ ??

Comment: It gets the value of artist from table 2 using the foreign key, and puts it into table 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to lookup artist value from ID , try below:

```
select table1.trackID,(select table2.artist from table2 where table2.artistid=table1.artistid) as artist from table1
```

I assume that Artistid is primary key in table2 so subquery will never return more than 1 record

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tracks T SET artist = (SELECT artist FROM artists A WHERE A.artist_id = T.artist_id)